# I've been trying to use the random.shuffle with tkinter. Can someone help me write a function to shuffle the colors on the buttons.

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, random, shuffle

I am still a beginner and I have yet to understand how to write a function, that works.
    import tkinter

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Shuffle Colors")

# The list of colors
colors = ['red','yellow', 'pink', 'purple','green', 'blue', 'orange','Brown']

#looping each color
for c in colors:

#Buttons
button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text=c, bg=c)
button1.pack(fill = tkinter.X)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why is there nothing inside of `for c in colors:`?

Comment: If you don't understand something as basic as how to write a function, please delete your question and go do some independent research. SO is not a replacement for a textbook or tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shuffle works in-place so:

```
import random
def my_shuffle(colors):
    random.shuffle(colors)
    return colors

new_colors = my_shuffle(colors)
```

but you dont really need a function - just do the shuffle as you need it - unless you need the original list to be unmodified